# Convert date day (05/12/2011 to 12th)

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to covert the date to the day number followed by "st", "nd", "rd" or "th depending on the day. I am new to javascript so have no idea where to start.

E.g.

05/01/2011 = 1st
05/02/2011 = 2nd
05/03/2011 = 3rd
05/12/2011 = 12th
05/22/2011 = 22nd

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: You may well just have to call `.getDate()` on the date, and use some logic to decide, 1/21/31 = *st*, 2/22 = *nd*, 3/23 = *rd*, else *th*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, get the date:

```
 var date = myval.getDate();
```

Then find the suffix:

```
 function get_nth_suffix(date) {
   switch (date) {
     case 1:
     case 21:
     case 31:
        return 'st';
     case 2:
     case 22:
        return 'nd';
     case 3:
     case 23:
        return 'rd';
     default:
        return 'th';
   }
 }
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/DZPSw/

Comment: Thanks. Looks simple enough as a switch :)

Comment: it should be pretty efficient, but in any event I was going for readability rather than performance.

Answer (score 9):

```
var date = new Date('05/12/2011').getDate(),
 ordinal = date + (date>10 && date<20 ? 'th' : {1:'st', 2:'nd', 3:'rd'}[date % 10] || 'th');
```

or

```
ordinal = date + ( [,'st','nd','rd'][/1?.$/.exec(date)] || 'th' );
```

Comment: Well this is the neatest method.  You would get better performance if you changed the initial condition to `date > 3 && date < 21` however.

Comment: perhaps, but I think it makes more logical sense this way since it means "I'm excluding the 'teens'"

Comment: regex way of doing this: `[,'st','nd','rd'][/1?.$/.exec(n)]||'th'`

Answer (score 2):

You might start with [JavaScript Date/Time Functions](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm) to get the Day number:

```
var theDate = myDateObj.GetDate(); // returns 1-31
```

Then you will need to write a rule to get the proper suffix.  Most of the time it will be `th`, except for the exceptions.  What are the exceptions?  1, 21, 31 = `st`, 2, 22 = `nd`, 3, 23 = `rd`, everything else is `th`.  So we can use mod `%` to check if it ends in 1, 2, or 3:

```
var nth = '';
if (theDate > 3 && theDate < 21)    // catch teens, which are all 'th'
    nth = theDate + 'th';
else if (theDate % 10 == 1)         // exceptions ending in '1'
    nth = theDate + 'st';
else if (theDate % 10 == 2)         // exceptions ending in '2'
    nth = theDate + 'nd';
else if (theDate % 10 == 3)         // exceptions ending in '3'
    nth = theDate + 'rd';
else
    nth = theDate + 'th';           // everything else
```

Here's a working demo showing the endings for 1-31: http://jsfiddle.net/6Nhn8/

Or you could be boring and [use a library](http://www.datejs.com/) :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Also 12, 13 = th these are the execptions you mentioned ;)

Comment: @JohnBoy: Yeah, I noticed that and fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this simple function the other day.  Although for a date you don't need the larger numbers, this will cater for higher values too (1013th, 36021st etc...)

```
var fGetSuffix = function(nPos){

    var sSuffix = "";

    switch (nPos % 10){
        case 1:
            sSuffix = (nPos % 100 === 11) ? "th" : "st";
            break;
        case 2:
            sSuffix = (nPos % 100 === 12) ? "th" : "nd";
            break;
        case 3:
            sSuffix = (nPos % 100 === 13) ? "th" : "rd";
            break;
        default:
            sSuffix = "th";
            break;
    }

    return sSuffix;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily with [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) using the `S` [format specifier](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers).