# JavaScript date suffix formatting

Tags: javascript

I have done my due diligence in investigating this and not had any success yet. Being rather green with JavaScript I am seeking some help. I am wanting to display the date

```
NOV2012<br>
2<sup>nd</sup><br>
5:00 PM
```

I have everything working (not my script) except being able to get the date suffix to change to st, nd, rd, or th as the case may be.

This is what I have:

```
<pre>  <abbr title="Month">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                      var d=new Date();
                      var month=new Array(12);
                      month[0]="Jan";
                      month[1]="Feb";
                      month[2]="Mar";
                      month[3]="Apr";
                      month[4]="May";
                      month[5]="Jun";
                      month[6]="Jul";
                      month[7]="Aug";
                      month[8]="Sep";
                      month[9]="Oct";
                      month[10]="Nov";
                      month[11]="Dec";
                      document.write(month[d.getMonth()]);
</script></abbr>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date()
    document.write(d.getDate())

    ordinal : function (number) {
            var d = number % 10;
            return (~~ (number % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
                (d === 1) ? 'st' :
                (d === 2) ? 'nd' :
                (d === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
        }
    });
    </script>
    <sup>%</sup> 
    <abbr><script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date()
    document.write(d.getFullYear())
    </script></abbr>
              <sub>

              <script type="text/javascript">
                      <!--
                      var currentTime = new Date()
                      var hours = currentTime.getHours()
                      var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
                      if (minutes < 10){
                      minutes = "0" + minutes
                      }
                      document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + " ")
                      if(hours > 11){
                      document.write("PM")
                      } else {
                      document.write("AM")
                      }
                      //-->
            </script>

          </sub>
</pre>
```

I know the issue is with this part:

```
<pre> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date()
    document.write(d.getDate())

    ordinal : function (number) {
            var d = number % 10;
            return (~~ (number % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
                (d === 1) ? 'st' :
                (d === 2) ? 'nd' :
                (d === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
        }
    });


    </script>

   < sup > % < /sup >
</pre>
```

but I can't seem to work out the right fix. This is where it is sitting:

http://www.bcreativeservices.com/

Thank you as always.

B

Comment: Look at your console (Developer tools, firebug, inspector,...). there is a syntax error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date day (05/12/2011 to 12th)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003530/convert-date-day-05-12-2011-to-12th)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, you have a syntax error assigning ordinal.  It *looks* like you were originally trying to make an object containing the key ordinal, but later changed it.

This is probably what you were going for:

```
function ordinal(number) {
  var d = number % 10;
  return (~~ (number % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
         (d === 1) ? 'st' :
         (d === 2) ? 'nd' :
         (d === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
}
```

Which works, but the double bitwise NOT `~~` makes your code a little difficult to follow.  I had to go look up what it was (I never use bitwise math) and I would recommend you not use it (unless you have good reason to be using it, of course).

According to [this question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript), you do get speed improvements.  However, these operations take fractions of microseconds, so the improvement is really negligible and only serves to make your code more difficult to understand.

---

Not too long ago, I wrote a function to provide these suffixes for dates.  After some slight modification (I added mine to the Date prototype), you'd get:

```
function ordinal(date) {
  return (date > 20 || date < 10) ? ([false, "st", "nd", "rd"])[(date%10)] || "th" : "th";
}
```

Which works on any valid date.

EDIT: It occurs to me that my version of the ordinal function is probably just as impossible to read.  For sanity's sake, here's a less condensed version with the same logic:

```
function ordinal(date) {
  if(date > 20 || date < 10) {
    switch(date%10) {
      case 1:
        return "st";
      case 2:
        return "nd";
      case 3:
        return "rd";
    }
  }
  return "th";
}
```