# Adding Date Suffixes

Tags: javascript, date, suffix

I have the following Javascript to display the date on a page, however I wanted to add in the "th", "st" and "rd" suffixes after each date number (ie. "6th").

Is there a way of doing this with the following code I currently have?

```
    <script language="Javascript">
<!-- 

// Array of day names
var dayNames = new Array("You're working today? It's Sunday","Hello, it's Monday","Hello, it's Tuesday","Hello, it's Wednesday",
    "Hello, it's Thursday","Hello, it's Friday","You're working today? It's Saturday");

// Array of month Names
var monthNames = new Array(
"January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
"August","September","October","November","December");

var now = new Date();
document.write (dayNames[now.getDay()] + ", " + 
now.getDate() + " " + 
monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + 
now.getFullYear() + ".");
// -->
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It was answered before here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13627586/2362973

Comment: There are [*many similar questions*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+ordinal).

Answer (score 0):

There are other solutions if you don't want to use a library.  Doing a quick search on StackOverflow led me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003530/convert-date-day-05-12-2011-to-12th).  You'll need to incorporate one of these functions into your code taking the value from `now.getDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dayNames[now.getDay()]` suggests that the key you are searching for is `now.getDay()`, which is not zero-based. I suggest that you move your value for Sunday in the end of the array and use `dayNames[now.getDay() - 1]` for more clarity.

On the subject, you can check this answer for the solution:
[Convert date day (05/12/2011 to 12th)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003530/convert-date-day-05-12-2011-to-12th)